# Does react re-render the component if it receives the same value in state

Tags: reactjs

> I am trying to check if I set the same value to state as it has previously , does it re-render the component , or if it found that value is same then it will avoid the re-rendering.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Class component

A component is unconditionally re-rendered after `setState` call. It doesn't matter if the state is the same value, i.e. a value that passes `===` comparison:

```
this.setState(state => state); // re-render
```

Or the same state that passes shallow object comparison:

```
this.setState(state => ({...state})); // re-render
```

In order to avoid unnecessary re-renders, component updates should be prevented, either with [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) or `shouldComponentUpdate`:

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference
>   between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a
>   shallow prop and state comparison.
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result
>   given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a
>   performance boost in some cases.

Notice that due to the use of virtual DOM in React, re-renders don't necessarily result in DOM re-rendering and may have acceptable performance.

## Function component

`useState` hook in functional components provides an alternative to stateful class components. One of major differences is that a component isn't re-rendered if it's the same value, i.e. a value that passes `===` comparison:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
...
setState(state => state); // no re-render
```

Otherwise a component is re-rendered:

```
setState(state => ({...state})); // re-render
```

Comment: And it will be re-rendered for _different_ values too. That's probably what you were implying, but I just want to be clear.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I agree that the wording could be improved.

Comment: With the function component when you say `no-op` that doesn't mean nothing is happening. The component function may actually be called one more time when setState is called with the same value. So there's _some_ operation; a `no-render` I would say ;) Check out: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474 and my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/devotis/jd12g7y4/16/

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Thanks for noticing, that's an interesting quirk but not really surprising, extra component calls can be expected due to concurrency, as it was said in the issue. Any way, I had no intention to emphasize no-op thing, it's not important to the answer.

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea how to do this when using React Hooks?

Comment: @Fitspade The last snippet does this

Comment: Oh my bad.. I must be blind lol.. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the [React Documentation - shouldComponentUpdate In Action](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action), they've talked about it in details, as a part of **Optimizing Performance** topic, and also give an example. This is the example:

[image]