# Function only updates states when it's invoked twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I have a function that's invoked on click to update the state, but only updates when it's clicked twice. For example, if I click once, it duplicates the prior update, and only when I click once more, the state gets updated.

```js
    const select = day => {
        let markedDay = day.dateString
        setSelected([...selected, markedDay])

        let obj = selected.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: { selected: true,  disableTouchEvent: true }}), {})

        setBooking(obj)
    }
```

The purpose of the function is to 1) gather the data in an array with the `setSelected` hook and 2) convert it to an object with newly assigned properties using `Object.assign` and `reduce`.

When the function is invoked once, the state `selected` from the hook `setSelected` shows either empty if invoked for the very first time or the previous state.  The same pattern goes for `obj`.  I want the function to update the state upon the first invocation, and not have to be invoked twice.

**Update**

I've simplified the function to following, but still the same problem:

```js
    const select = day => {
        let markedDay = day.dateString
        setSelected({...selected, [markedDay]: { selected: true, disableTouchEvent: true  }})
    }
```

The function is for react-native-calendars and an example of `selected` would be:

```js
  "2019-11-18": Object {
    "selected": true,
    "disableTouchEvent": true,
  }
```

Each time I select a date, I want to see the above object updated on the state, but only when I click it for the second time, it gets updated.

Comment: I think more context is needed to answer this. What is selected? What does setSelected do?

Comment: @Matt I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting state in React is async, so the updates won't be reflected to the state until next render. The issue with your code is that you're using the new value of state right after it's set, however the updated value will be available only on the next component render. To fix this issue you can reuse the updated value of `selected` before setting it to state:

```
const select = day => {
  let markedDay = day.dateString
  const newSelected = [...selected, markedDay];

  let obj = newSelected.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {
    [v]: {
      selected: true,
      disableTouchEvent: true
    }
  }), {})
  setSelected(newSelected)
  setBooking(obj);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the updated state value in the `setBooking`, you'd need to make that call inside the `useEffect` while tracking `selected` variable.

```
const select = day => {
  let markedDay = day.dateString

  setSelected([...selected, markedDay]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  let obj = selected.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {
    [v]: {
      selected: true,
      disableTouchEvent: true
    }
  }), {})

  setBooking(obj);
}, [selected])
```

That might be a preferable approach when you have more complex state.

Comment: this is a brilliant answer. So there's no way to natively use the React hooks in an synchronous way?

Comment: @Kevvv you'll need to use `useEffect` in that case and track the changed state value. I've updated the answer. But contrary to the `setState`, the hook version doesn't have a second callback argument.

Comment: thank you for the updated answer. Just out of curiosity, could the reason the state was not being updated on my code `selected.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: { selected: true,  disableTouchEvent: true }}), {})` be because I was modifying the state `selected` directly instead of through `newSelected` like the way you did? By modifying the state directly, the `useState` would think that `selected` hasn't changed so it doesn't render. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52625068/10116367) shows that the `useState` hook won't re-render if the value passed is the same.

Comment: yep, that's the issue with modifying state directly - the changes are not picked up by React.

Answer (score 0):

I can only hazard a guess on what's happening, but I think that what we're looking at here is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). I'm guessing that either setBooking or setSelected is supposed to take values from your state and adjust the rendering of the final product, yes?

The problem is that setting state in react is asynchronous. If I say

```
console.log(this.state.foo) // 'bar'
this.setState({foo:'fizz'})
console.log(this.state.foo) // still 'bar'
```

react is still setting the state in the background; it hasn't finished yet, so I get the old value.

There are three methods to fixing this error.

Method 1: Make your render statements depend on the state/call functions that depend on state. That way, whenever the state updates, what you're rendering updates.

Method 2: Pass the parameters that you wanted to store in state as arguments to your setBooking or setSelected function(s). No need to worry about race conditions if they're just receiving the values.

Method 3: You can write force setState to be synchronous.

`this.setState({foo:'bar'},()=>{
//do something
}`)

The "do something" portion of this code will not execute until after state has been set. It has a little bit of code smell (You're not taking advantage of asynch, after all) but sometimes it's necessary if you want to re-use a function in componentDidMount as well as in the life cycle of your component.