# Re-rendering behavior with class and functional component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, render

I did a lot of research about `Impure component vs Pure component`, I am so confused about it and their behavior with `Class & Functional components`. So, please read carefully.

***Question #1*:**
Is the definition of pure component is that "Pure component doesn't re-render when the value of changed state is the same value as the previous one", right?

**Question #2** I can see that `Functional Component` behaves as pure component by default, because it doesn't re-renders the component if incoming state value is same as current one, am i right?.

```
const Home = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
    
    const handleCount = () => {
        setCount(1)
    }

    console.log(`HOME ${count} - Functional Component`);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleCount}>Click Me</button>
            <div>{count + 1}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Home
```

[image]

See, It doesn't re-render when I click on button. Then it means **functional components** are **pure components** by default, right?

**Question #3:** Using **functional component**, when I set the default state to `0` and then call the `setState` like: **setCount(1)** then it should re-render only on first click because state has changed. But, when I click on 2nd time on button, it again re-renders, even current state value (1) is equal to incoming state (1), then why it re-renders on same value in `functional component`?

```
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
    const handleCount = () => {
        setCount(1)
    }
```

[image]

I am so much confused with different definitions and different behaviors again and again.
Can someone help me with this?
**Question #4:** When component re-renders? On `setState` function call or when state value updates?
**Question #5:** If my default state value is `true`, and i call the update function like: `setState(true)`. Will it still update the state value or it will not update the state value because it's same?

Comment: For function components React.memo() is used to shallow compare properties, not state. So if you wrap you component with React.memo and new properties have === equality, then component won't re-render. Regarding state update - component re-renders when state is updated, not when function is called - it makes sense to re-render only when new state is available. If state value is same, it won't update it as there is no need to do so.

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Thanks for this info, and please read my questions about functional components. 1. Why it re-renders on 2nd click when state value is same as previous. 2. Are the functional components are pure by default?

Comment: I am following this question regarding this part. Not sure as well.

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Hmm, I guess, someone help me with this thing

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas You said that component re-renders when state value updates, and if incoming state value is same then it will not update the state. Then why Class component re-renders on same state values? It's being re-rendered because same value is being updated again, no?

Comment: In class components - yes. Class component if it extends Component will re-render no matter if state is equal to previous state. If it extends PureComponent, then this component implements shouldComponentUpdate method which shallow checks current props and state with incoming props and state. You can have you own shouldComponentUpdate implementation (even if your class is not Pure Component). 
You can read more https://stackoverflow.com/a/52625068/9186426

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas that's good. But some of my questions still left. Hope, they'll clear soon too.