# React useState with object: how to avoid the initial re-rendering, caused by the call to setState with same values?

Tags: reactjs

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't find a clear anwser here. I'm trying to minimize re-renderings, at least avoid useless renderings like in this case.

1. The `state` is an object, because I'd like to set both `loading` and `products` properties with a **single `setState` call**
2. Initially, `loading` is `true` because I'm sure that `useEffect` is called at least once
3. Calling `setState` inside `useEffect` will trigger an **useless immediate re-render**, because I think how object are compared (**shallow vs deep**)

Actual code:

```
export const ProductsIndex = () => {
  console.log('[ProductsIndex] Rendering');

  const [state, setState] = useState({ loading: true, products: [], pages: 1 });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[ProductsIndex] useEffect');

    setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: true });
    axios.get('/api/products', params)
      .then(res => {
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: false, products: res.data });
      });

    // fetch
  }, [params]);
};
```

I can think at this solution, but I really don't know if there is a better way to handle this use cases:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('[ProductsIndex] useEffect');

  setState(prev => prev.loading ? prev : { ...prev, loading: true });
}, []);
```

Comment: What's the point of avoiding that initial re-render?

Comment: Have your tried creating a separate state for the loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be simple enough to only set the state initially if it's different from the current state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[ProductsIndex] useEffect');
    if (!state.loading) {
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: true });
    }
```

But setting state unnecessarily usually *shouldn't be something you need to worry about*. It's not a problem for React, and a well designed app usually shouldn't depend on the component *not* re-rendering at a certain point. If it causes problems for you, you can use various hooks to monitor and account for state/prop changes if needed, especially `useMemo` and the cleanup function returned by `useEffect`.

If a component happens to re-render twice when an app starts up, or even 5 or 10 times - it'll usually be completely imperceptible to the user, and so isn't worth worrying about. You just need to make sure that other logic in your app is also written with the possibility of re-renderings in mind.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was doing in my original question, single-line. I was looking for confirmations about the "right" way (or better way) to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the way you are going about this seems to be wrong. You can probably rewrite this in a better manner using custom hooks.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"


export default function useFetch(url){

    const [data,setData] = useState(null)
    const [error,setError] = useState(null)
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        (
            async function(){
                try{
                    setLoading(true)
                    const response = await axios.get(url)
                    setData(response.data)
                }catch(err){
                    setError(err)
                }finally{
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            }
        )()
    }, [url])

    return { data, error, loading }

}
```

Try something like this.
Reference: https://dev.to/shaedrizwan/building-custom-hooks-in-react-to-fetch-data-4ig6

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your first `setState` triggers a re-render even though the state objects are identical, is because, as React official documentation [explains](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update), states use the [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#description) comparison algorithm. It is easy to see then what happens:

```js
const obj1 = { loading: true, products: [], pages: 1 };
const obj2 = { ...obj1, loading: true};

Object.is(obj1, obj2); //false
```

The reason for this behaviour is that, simply, despite having the same values, `obj1` and `obj2` are different *references* of objects. So, as @CertainPerformance stated, why not simply control before setting the state?

Another approach might be the one suggested in this very useful question: [Does react re-render the component if it receives the same value in state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624612/does-react-re-render-the-component-if-it-receives-the-same-value-in-state)