# If the value of the new state is same as that of the previous state, then does the component not render again?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, console.log

In this example, upon clicking the "click" button, my console is logging "clicked" but then at the same time, I'm also updating the state using setCount, so shouldn't the component Re-render and the console should log "rendered" each time the button is clicked.
However, the rendered is only displayed once.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import GenerateList from './generate_list';

function App() {


const [count,setCount] = React.useState(1);


console.log("Rendered");
function update()
{
  setCount(1);
  console.log("clicked")
}

return (
  <div className='container'  >
    <div className='sidebar'>
      
  <button onClick={update}>click</button>
      {count}
    </div>
    <div className='main'>
      <div className='notes'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It appears that your test answers your question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does react re-render the component if it receives the same value in state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624612/does-react-re-render-the-component-if-it-receives-the-same-value-in-state)

Comment: in the case for where state is a value type (int in your example) - yes.  No render will happen as state is the same ```setCount(1);```.  for ref types (arrays, objects) it can be a little different depending on implementation.  if you are not mutating state - you typically will replace the ref in state.  i.e. when there is a change in an array you should create a new array, and set this back in state.  if you update the original array the reference wont change, so the render wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state to be 1 each time. React only re-renders if the state changes. Therefore `console.log("Rendered")` is not run again.